# unix sort is giving different results for different users

Tags: sorting, unix, csh

I wanted to sort a file name reportA with following contents

```
pat_int_parallel_all


/projects/test
-v ../../../../../../te
min_custom.v
-v ../../../../../../tes
-y ../../../../../../test_
-y ../../../../../../test_lib/test
../../../../../../tesla
/projects/checklist
../../../../../../test_lib/LIB
../../../../../../telib/av
../../../../../../telib/te
+libext+.v
+incdir+/projectsst_relea/ana
```

when i tried sort -u -r reportA >output .
I got this result

```
-y ../../../../../../test_lib/test
-y ../../../../../../test_
-v ../../../../../../tes
-v ../../../../../../te 
../../../../../../test_lib/LIB
../../../../../../test 
../../../../../../telib/te
../../../../../../telib/av
/projects/test /projects/checklist 
pat_int_parallel_all min_custom.v
+libext+.v
+incdir+/projectsst_relea/ana
```

My locale output is **en_US**

```
LANG=en_US
LC_CTYPE="en_US"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US"
LC_TIME="en_US"
LC_COLLATE="en_US"
LC_MONETARY="en_US"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US"
LC_PAPER="en_US"
LC_NAME="en_US"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US"
LC_ALL=
```

But for the other user with same sort command it resulted in a different output.

```
pat_int_parallel_all
min_custom.v
/projects/test
/projects/checklist
../../../../../../test_lib/LIB
../../../../../../tesla
../../../../../../telib/te
../../../../../../telib/av
-y ../../../../../../test_lib/test
-y ../../../../../../test_
-v ../../../../../../tes
-v ../../../../../../te
+libext+.v
+incdir+/projectsst_relea/ana
```

My friends locale output is **C**

```
LANG=C
LC_CTYPE="C"
LC_NUMERIC="C"
LC_TIME="C"
LC_COLLATE="C"
LC_MONETARY="C"
LC_MESSAGES="C"
LC_PAPER="C"
LC_NAME="C"
LC_ADDRESS="C"
LC_TELEPHONE="C"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C"
LC_ALL=C
```

I was wondering why a normal uinx sort command is giving two different results when my sort alias,SHELL version is same as other user. Even cshrc settings are same.
Is it due to the special characters?

Can someone explain what's wrong here.

Comment: Your friend's sort is typical for US locale. Yours is not. Please edit your question and add the output of the `locale` command.

Comment: Thanks @Amadan . How do i change locale variable

Comment: `C` should behave the same as `en_US` for this. Please add the full output of your `locale` command. Another things is to check whether the file has any invisible characters using `xxd`.

Comment: I have updated the question with complete locale output.

Comment: Sorry, that's super strange and I can't explain it. Even with your settings I'm still getting your friend's output; and I know nothing else that would affect it.

Comment: @Amadan I tried the other way around, I tried setting LANG to C . I am getting same output as my friend.
`setenv LANG C`
Now sort output is proper.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ground reason of the different behavior of `sort` is the value of `LC_COLLATE`. The output of `man 7 locale` says:

> LC_COLLATE
>
> This category governs the collation rules used for sorting and regular
>   expressions, including character equivalence classes and
>   multicharacter  collating elements.  This locale category changes the
>   behavior of the functions `strcoll(3)` and `strxfrm(3)`, which are used
>   to compare strings in the local alphabet. For example, the German
>   sharp s is sorted as "ss".

My (very quick) analysis of `sort` [source code](http://ftp.gnu.org/gnu/coreutils/coreutils-8.30.tar.xz), is that it transforms lines of text to be sorted with `strxfrm()` to get a  *basis of comparison, so that byte
strings that would otherwise considered to be equal are considered equal here even if their bytes differ* (sic).

Regarding the fact that you still get the same output is, as said by @Amadan,  quite strange. Are you sure you have set the locale properly? Could you try `LC_COLLATE="C" sort -ru your_file`.

Comment: The one you suggested is working. 
But I used  `LC_ALL=C sort -u -r filename` ,which is giving me desired results.

Comment: `LC_COLLATE=C sort` still gives me inconsistent results. `LC_ALL=C sort` seems to be better?